# SQL запрос с оператором LIKE поиск по совпадений по двум словам

Tags: php, sql

Такая ситуация:
1) Есть запрос `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%'.$search.'%'`
2) Допустим есть фраза `Advanced O`, то он выведет все строки с вхождением этой фразы
3) Как сделать чтобы слово/символ через пробел искался отдельно, т.е. при фразе `Advenced O` вывел не только строку `Advenced Other`, но и `Advenced Error`

Получается нужно чтобы вывело строки с вхождением слова `Advenced` и буквы "О"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменяйте пробелы в переменной на знак подстановки `%`. Например так:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%' + replace(.$search.,' ','%') + '%'
```

Но в этом случае в результатах отсутствовать строки, где буква `O` идет перед словом `Advanced`. То есть строка вида `Other Advanced` в выборку не попадет.

Comment: Спасибо, как можно сделать чтобы ещё можно было сделать выборку до не зависимо от положения ключевых слов(Как вы и писали "Other Advanced")?

Comment: name like '%Advanced% [or/and] name like'%O%'

Answer (score 2):

> как можно сделать чтобы ещё можно было сделать выборку до не зависимо
>   от положения ключевых слов

Например, так:

```
// Разбиваем исходную строку на фрагменты:
$words = explode(' ', $string); // или preg_split()

// Теперь получаем все перестановки слов, то есть:
// $permutations[0] = [ "O", "Advanced" ]
// $permutations[1] = [ "Advanced", "O" ]
// Как? Вопрос ОЧЕНЬ часто задаваемый, гуглится без проблем.
// Да и для тренировки можно самому подумать :)
$permutations = get_permutations( $words );

// Формируем строки для LIKE:
$likes = array();
foreach( $permutations as $permutation )
{
    // $likes[] = "%O%Advanced%" и т.д.
    $likes[] = '%'.join( '%', $permutation ).'%';
}

// Ну и в самом простом случае:
$where = '`name` LIKE "'.join( '" OR `name` LIKE "', $likes ).'"';
// $where = `name` LIKE "%O%Advanced%" OR `name` LIKE "%Advanced%O%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Примените к $search функцию типа replace, и замените пробелы на %.

Опоздал. :-)